# How to override 'self' in Jsonnet?

Tags: jsonnet

I am trying to create a template which has some defaults but these should be overridden if a custom values file is provided. The problem is some of my variables in the object are built from other variables in the same object, like `adjective: 'Good' + self.fruit`. This does not get overridden.

`std.mergePatch` does not produce expected result because it renders the whole object (which has already made us of `self.fruit` by now) and then overrides `fruit`.

```
local myobj = { 
  adjective: 'Good ' + self.fruit.name, 
  fruit: {
    name: 'apple', 
    qty: 1
  },
};
myobj
```

produces correct result when nothing is overridden:

```
{
  "adjective": "Good apple",
  "fruit": {
    "name": "apple",
    "qty": 1
  }
}
```

But when I try to override it with another variable, it still takes the default value if I use `std.mergePatch` as follows:

```
local config = {
  fruit: {
    name: 'banana',
    size: 'large',
  },
};

local myobj = { 
  adjective: 'Good ' + self.fruit.name, 
  fruit: {
    name: 'apple', 
    qty: 1
  },
};

std.mergePatch(myobj, config)
```

Produces (notice the wrong fruit name in `adjective`):

```
{
  "adjective": "Good apple",
  "fruit": {
    "name": "banana",
    "qty": 1,
    "size": "large"
  }
}
```

And if I directly add the two objects, it misses the extra information:

```
local config = {
  fruit: {
    name: 'banana',
    size: 'large',
  },
};

local myobj = { 
  adjective: 'Good ' + self.fruit.name, 
  fruit: {
    name: 'apple', 
    qty: 1
  },
};

myobj + config
```

Produces (notice the missing default `qty: 1`):

```
{
  "adjective": "Good banana",
  "fruit": {
    "name": "banana",
    "size": "large"
  }
}
```

How to achieve this with Jsonnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std.mergePatch()` will combine those already "finalized" objects, thus overriding `self` fields won't be possible.

Adding the two objects just needs the `+:` to be able to derive from parent's field:

> jsonnet-stackoverflow-56971012.jsonnet src:

```
local config = {
  fruit+: {
    name: 'banana',
    size: 'large',
  },
};

local myobj = {
  adjective: 'Good ' + self.fruit.name,
  fruit+: {
    name: 'apple',
    qty: 1
  },
};

myobj + config
```

> jsonnet-stackoverflow-56971012.jsonnet output:

```
{
   "adjective": "Good banana",
   "fruit": {
      "name": "banana",
      "qty": 1,
      "size": "large"
   }
}
```

Note the `+` is not needed for `myobj`, although IMO it's a good idea to keep it there in case you'd need itself to override a (future) base object.